# Understanding the implementation of Java BitSet class

Tags: java, bitset

BitSet object provides somewhat unclear results when I tried to test it and make sense of it.

main:

```
byte f = (byte)0b00101000;
byte s = (byte)0b11111111;
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{f, s};
BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(bytes);

printlnLog("Input bitset: " + bs);
printlnLog("Input bitset length: " + bs.size());
```

Output:

```
Input bitset: {3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
Input bitset length: 64
```

Output makes no sense for me. I do not understand the underlying logic of BitSet. I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you read the docs?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 actually I did, still confused... not always docs make clear sense of what is going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this clear enough?

```
byte f = (byte)0b00101000;
// Bits 0 to 7   --5-3---                  
byte s = (byte)0b11111111;
// Bits 8 to 15  54321098
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{f, s};
BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(bytes);
```

And the 64 is due to the number of bits currently allocated. The maximum bit number of set bits can be obtained by calling `bs.length()`.

There is nothing to indicate the trailing unset bits defined by any constructor or method, but this isn't necessary. This doesn't hurt since you aren't punished by using an index (e.g. in BitSet.get(int index)) with a value beyond this or that "end" of a BitSet.

Comment: Okay, I understood the array thing. But what's about the bitset length? Should not it be 16? Because we have 16 bits...

Comment: *"size()
Returns the number of bits of space actually in use by this BitSet to represent bit values."* - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html